# how to get arbitrarily 500 items from dynamody without scanning the entire table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to get arbitrary 500 items (guaranteed there are more items than that) from dynamodb, and looks like the `get_item` or `query` methods require primary key when retrieving items from ddb, and `scan` is scanning entire table which is time-consuming for a large table. is there any way that I can get arbitrary 500 items without providing primary key nor scanning the entire table? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query() doesn't require a primary key...

It does require the hash key half of a composite ( hash key + sort key) primary key.

In other words, to use Query() to return multiple records, you have to be using a composite primary key.

If you don't have a composite primary key, then Scan() is your only option on the for the table itself.

However, you could also create a global secondary index (GSI) that has a composite primary key and use Query() on that.

Also note that Scan() won't necessarily *"scan the entire table"*; as a single scan operation [reads up to the maximum number of items set (if using the Limit parameter) or a maximum of 1 MB of data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html)

Query() has a similar 1MB read limit...

In both cases, to read more than 1MB of data, you have to call the operation in a loop passing in the returned `LastEvaluatedKey` as `ExclusiveStartKey`